# Kmz features are labeled by global ID. Can I label them differently?

Tags: shapefile, convert, kml, kmz, naming-conventions

So I have taken a layer from ArcMap and exported it to a kmz.  It is a map of electric utilities in a single county.  When I look at the kmz in google earth, it is mapped correctly, however, every utility line that has a name is labeled by the global ID column from layer attribute table.  The label I want is under a different column in the attribute table. (as you can see on the image of the table, I don't need the {A95C0012... number, I need the CircuitID1 to be the name.)  Can I export a kmz that will name each feature based upon a different column within the attribute table?[image: exported kmz]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the "Layer to KML" tool in ArcGIS, then you need to do a bit of setup before exporting, to set which field gets used for the feature name (and other options).  You'll want to go into the layer properties and choose one of the options from the documentation below.

"If labels are turned on, the layer's label field or expression will be used for the feature name in the KML. If labels are not turned on, the layer's display field or expression will be used for the name. If neither of these layer properties are set, values from a field named Name will be used for the name."

For more documentation see the ArcGIS page on KML conversion:
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/kml-conversion.htm, and look for "Feature name" on that page.

Note that you can also control the contents of the popup balloon by using the "HTML Popup" tab in the layer properties.